# Wcf service not returning cookies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing one windows phone application. It require authentication to site. I send userid and password to WCF service which will check for authentication.

Service-side code:

**Service.svc.cs**

```
public CookieContainer GetConnect(string uid, string password)
//public string GetConnect(string uid, string password)
{
    try
    {
         HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/Login1.action");
        req.Method = "POST";
        CookieContainer con = new CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer = con;
        req.CookieContainer.Add(GetCookies());
        req.KeepAlive = true;

        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        req.Referer = "http://example.com/content/index.html";

        byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username=" + uid + "&password=" + password);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uid, password);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

        string str = req.GetRequestStream();
        str.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        str.Close();

        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        string iduri = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res.ResponseUri.Query).Get("id");
        if (iduri != "")
        {
            return con; 
            //return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            res.Close();
            str.Close();

            return null;
            //return "Fail";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**IService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    CookieCollection GetCookies();

    [OperationContract]
    CookieContainer GetConnect(string uname, string password);
    //string GetConnect(string uname, string password);
}
```

Client-side code:

**Login.xaml.cs**

```
void svc_Get_Connected(object send, GetConnectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var cc = new CookieContainer();
    cc=e.Result;
}
```

When I retun **con** object it give following error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://example.com:3922/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

How to return `CookieContainer`?

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to read - it helps if you work on the formatting, remove irrelevant (commented) code. Note that you can edit your question at any time. Either way it's unclear to me what the whole cookie-thing has to do with the problem: the error you post indicates a problem with your endpoint configurations?

Comment: So you want to return `CookieContainer` from WCF service method? You can return only classes decorated by `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

Comment: Yes I want to return CookieContainer

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your return object class so that WCF can serialize it, for example:

```
[DataContract]
public class CookieContainer 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    // you get the idea...
}
```

Don't forget to build your service, run it and then either refresh the client service reference or manually re-generate the client side proxy code & config.